# Bounded and finite - examples of distinction

Tags: real-analysis

What is the distinction between a bounded function, and a finite function? Is there any example of two functions that satisfies only one of them?

> **Definition** If $|f(x)|<+\infty \forall x \in E$, we say $f$ is finite.
>
> **Definition** If there exist a finite number $M$ such that $|f(x)| \leq M \forall x \in E$, we say $f$ is bounded.

Thank you.

Comment: Some real analysis texts allow functions to take the value $\infty$.  So something like $f(x) = x$ is finite but not bounded, while, say, $f(x) = \frac{1}{\lvert x \rvert}$ for nonzero $x$ and $f(0) = \infty$, would be neither finite nor bounded.

Comment: With these definitions, every bounded function is finite, but not every finite function is bounded. Consider $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1/x &, x \neq 0\\ 0 &, x = 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: Oh, got it - so $1/x$ approaches to $\infty$ actually means less than $\infty$, hence is finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To echo MartianInvader's answer in the comments, $f(x)=x$ is finite but not bounded. That's got to be the simplest possible example!